# OneDrive Graph API to detect if file is opened by any user before moving to other folder

Tags: onedrive

I am using OneDrive REST API to upload and share document with multiple users. I need to move the document from one folder to another folder after all users finish their edits. This action will be initiated by user, however it fails if any user kept open the document or it was stuck in office upload center (Desktop client).

Is there any way to detect if the item/document is busy before attempting to move? Is there any OneDrive API available to detect which user opened the document?